# Computing wedge product of two positive closed currents

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I am new to the theory of currents and pursuing this note-"https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~tien-cuong.dinh/Cours2005/Master/cours.pdf". My concept of product of positive currents is limited to that note and based on that I am stuck in computing the following two $(2,2)$ currents(distributions) on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (Exercise 6.3.5 and 6.3.6):

1. $dd^{c}\log|z_{1}|\wedge dd^{c}\log|z_{2}|$ and
2. $(dd^{c}log\|z\|)^{2}$.

My feeling is that both of them will be dirac-delta at the origin but unable to show it precisely.

Comment: Your first statement holds for $u\in\mathcal{C}^2$, otherwise (like in the case of $u=\log|f|$ where f can have zeroes in the domain) $\frac{{\partial}^2 u}{\partial z_{k}\partial\bar{z_{l}}}(z)$ is a distribution and product of distributions is not defined. So, I don't see how "det" function is coming.

Comment: How $(dd^{c}\log\|z\|)^{2}$ is the standard volume form, is it not $(dd^{c}\|z\|)^{2} ?$.

Answer (score 0):

Using by Poincare-Lelong formula [see https://www.scielo.cl/pdf/proy/v32n1/art01.pdf] we get $dd^c\log |z_1|=[z_1=0]$ and $dd^c \log |z_2|=[z_2=0]$. From $\text{supp}(T_1 \wedge T_2)\subset \text{supp}(T_1)\cap \text{supp}(T_2)$ implies that $\text{supp}(dd^c\log |z_1|\wedge dd^c\log |z_2|)=\{z=0\}$. It means that $dd^c\log |z_1|\wedge dd^c\log |z_2|=C\delta_0$. In otherside we get $[z_k=0]=\frac{1}{2i}dz_k\wedge d\bar{z}_k,k\in\{1,2\}$ and
$$\langle dd^c\log |z_1| \wedge dd^c\log |z_2|, \phi \rangle=\langle dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge dy_1 \wedge dy_2, \phi \rangle=\phi(0)$$
and $C=1$. Last answer is
$dd^c\log |z_1| \wedge dd^c\log |z_2|=\delta_0(z)$.